# Switch between editable and non editable mode in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I am using ag-grid to display and modify data.How Can I switch between editable and non editable for the hole ag-grid. Can I do this with the grid api.

this is my default config:

```
this.defaultDefs = {           
    suppressMovable: true,     
    enableColResize: true,     
    editable: true,            
};
```

Can I change editable dynamically?

Answer (score 18):

editable can be either a boolean as you have it, or a function

If you use the function form you can determine on a cell by cell basis if you want the given cell to be editable

```
editable: function(params) {
   return true; // true/false based on params (or some other criteria) value
}
```

Comment: thx I will try this by the way does this function affect the column that are always not editable I have same column where I specify editable:false 
will this function affect them

Comment: You can set editable by column too - this will override the setting on the defaultDefs

Comment: So if defaultDefs get a function or a Boolean it will always be override

Comment: No, what i mean is that any setting on detaultCols can be overridin on a column by column basis. Set any default on defaultDefs (say to be not editable) then override on a column by column basis as appropriate. Note that the default setting for a column is for it to NOT be editable

Answer (score 1):

you can set editable property by your way just create another function isEditable(columnName) which will give you boolean result.

```
this.defaultDefs = {           
    suppressMovable: true,     
    enableColResize: true,     
    editable: isEditable(column),            
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a logic check in the [cellEditingStarted](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#start-stop-editing-events) callback, calling the stop() when the check fails. You may need to write some css to style it or add a toast/notification to give the user feedback on why they're not able to edit.

Comment: One side-effect of this is that the edit interface will briefly flicker in between starting / canceling the edit, better to use a callback for the editable property, this way you can prevent entering edit mode at all on a cell-by-cell level if desired

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

1. editable: (params) => your logic
2. update your date
3. call api.redrawRows({ rowNodes: [*node*] })

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `suppressClickEdit` in the grid options for a quick disabling:

```
gridOptions: {
   suppressClickEdit: true | false,
   ...
}
```

See: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/cell-editing-start-stop/#no-click-editing

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach

```
        editable: (params:any)=> params.data.isEdit === 'edit' ?  true :  false
```

add it to the columndefinitions

*

*Note:  isEdit === 'edit' is your custom logic*

*